# Access denied error using asymmetric binding in web host server - .NET

Tags: asp.net, web-services, security, access-denied, x509certificate2

I'm getting an Access denied error when I attempt to make a web service request.  The web service requires an asymmetric security binding.  The call is made via a webpage that references a .NET dll that references the web service.  All of this works fine on our server but we loaded it up at a web hosting company we got hit with this error. 
My theory is that whatever the `GetKeyPairHelper` method does it requires the ability to write a file to do it while we don't have access to the location it tries to write to.  The support people at this company ran a trace for us and these were the last two lines:

> 06:03.1    w3wp.exe    5860    CreateFile  C:\ProgramData  NAME COLLISION  >Desired Access: Read Data/List Directory, Synchronize, Disposition: Create, Options: >Directory, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Open Reparse Point, Attributes: N, ShareMode: Read, >Write, AllocationSize: 0
>
> 06:03.1    w3wp.exe    5860    CreateFile  C:\ProgramData  ACCESS DENIED   >Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, >Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a

Looks like something trying to write to `C:\ProgramData` but what? And why? And how do I get around it?  I'm hoping there is some way to configure this so it doesn't have to write a file.  Perhaps this job can be performed in memory or directed to an area we have access to.

**Stacktrace:**

> Error: Access is denied. : Server stack trace: 
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer) 
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle) 
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair() 
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize) 
>   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey() 
>   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.get_PrivateKey() 
>   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey.GetSignatureFormatter(String algorithm) 
>   at System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature(SecurityKey signingKey) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroSendSecurityHeader.CompletePrimarySignatureCore(SendSecurityHeaderElement[] signatureConfirmations, SecurityToken[] signedEndorsingTokens, SecurityToken[] signedTokens, SendSecurityHeaderElement[] basicTokens) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSignature() at System.ServiceModel.Security.SendSecurityHeader.CompleteSecurityApplication() 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityAppliedMessage.OnWriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlDictionaryWriter writer) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.WriteMessage(XmlWriter writer) 
>   at CustomMessageEncoder.CustomTextMessageEncoder.WriteMessage(Message message, Int32 maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, Int32 messageOffset) 
>   in C:\xxxxx\CustomEncoders\CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs:line 86

**Code:**

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, this.writerSettings);
    message.WriteMessage(writer); //'line 86' in stacktrace.  
    writer.Close();

    byte[] messageBytes = stream.GetBuffer();
    int messageLength = (int)stream.Position;
    stream.Close();

    int totalLength = messageLength + messageOffset;
    byte[] totalBytes = bufferManager.TakeBuffer(totalLength);
    Array.Copy(messageBytes, 0, totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);
    //maybe parse message around here...
    ArraySegment<byte> byteArray = new ArraySegment<byte>(totalBytes, messageOffset, messageLength);
    return byteArray;
}
```

Comment: What code is at line 86 of CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs? Where do you use `System.IdentityModel.SignedXml.ComputeSignature` or `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2.get_PrivateKey()` that are shown in the stacktrace?

Comment: When I create the security binding all of the certificate information is added at that time.  The last line that I have control over is where I attempt to write the message to the stream(line 86):  message.WriteMessage(writer);  I assume the stacktrace you see is generated by the .NET libraries acting on the parameters that I added when creating the binding.  I'm not an expert in this area so I could be way off base.  At some point it looks like 'CreateProvHandle' attempts an action in a directory it does not have access to.

Comment: It is important to know the configuration of wcf service. It tries to get some certificate when you call `message.WriteMessage(writer);`. What certificate could it try to get? Does it have access to the private key of that certificate? what AppPool does the service run under? Has this user rights to access this certificate and its private key?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm not using WCF in this case.  The framework is .NET 4, I import system.servicemodel and created all custom bindings.  Also, this works completely fine on our own server.  It's only when we load it in a shared environment (web hosting service) that this issue crops up.  The sys admin tells that yes we do have permissions to the private keys.  I asked them to change the app pool to .net 4.  I'm not sure what certificate would be causing the issue.  There are 4 involved - the PKI for the service and a CA a chain cert and our signing cert.

Comment: CA certificate should be OK, chain cert too because these should not have private keys mapped. So you should check signing cert and PKI for the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happened here is that the hosting company was hosting our site on a shared server and so rightfully denied access to the C:\ProgramData folder which, further down the directory contains C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys which is the folder you need access to in order to use certificates based security.  Their solution for us was to allow access to this folder for our app pool only.  Works like a charm.